# How do I put an HTML textarea into a JavaScript web alert/popup?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I'm  trying to make the text from an `Alert` to be copyable to `clipboard`, which works, however the pasted text does not retain line breaks. I can't seem to find a way to make the text in an `Alert` into a `textarea`. If there's another way to do this I'm open to it, however I'd like to avoid addons.

I'm able to get line breaks in the `Alert`. I'm using `\n`, but it does not retain after pasting.

```
<body>
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
      function test(){
          alert("line 1 \n line 2 \n line 3");
      }
  </script>

  <button onClick="test()">button</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

The `function` and `button` works as planned, but when I use `Ctrl+C` to copy it, the line breaks are not retained when I paste it elsewhere.

Comment: It is a window object and cannot interpret HTML tags. Whether or not it retains newline depends on where you paste it.

Comment: Copy&Paste from the alert-box only works on Firefox on my site. You may consider using something like modals

Comment: I am often using prompt('', data) instead, but there are sometimes size limits in chrome 2000B(?) Anyway in Windows it works w/o problems, but would tell I have to put \r\n in the string to have proper line breaks. And you do not see content - only something selected by cursor color, but immediate Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Insert works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to copy content to the clipboard, putting the content in an alert is not a good way to accomplish it. Alerts aren't designed to do anything but deliver string messages in such a way that blocks interaction with the page. You can't put rich content like HTML into them.

They are generally not a good solution for anything other than interrupting interaction with the page.

Web browsers support direct interaction with the system clipboard, you can read more about the clipboard API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a modal to display the text like you want it instead of using an alert. I think you would get the functionality you're looking for without the restrictions of using an alert.

You could put a disabled textarea in the modal so that the text couldn't be accidentally changed before the copy/paste.